# Issue with method not returning values in interpolation nuxjs/vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

In my nuxtjs app static folder I have a file called `data.json`

in my component I use this data like so

```
<script>
import data from '~/static/data.json';
export default {
    data ({ params }) {
        return {
            data
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

now I have a method that will basically take values from that data and create a little counting up animation like so

```
methods: {
    countUp(value) {
        for (let i = 0; i <= value; i++) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                return i;
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

and in my template I am calling it like so

```
<template>
    <div>
       <p>{{countUp(data.number)}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

now the expected result is for the number to quickly change from 0 to the value but nothing is being printed on the dom if I inspect the html element its empty??

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What's the `timers` package?

Comment: @DecadeMoon it was auto imported via vscode when I wrote `setTimeout()` I have removed it and the issue still occurs

Comment: You never return anything from your `countUp` method, you on;y return from a sub function created in that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't work the way you think it does:

- You can't return a value from inside the callback function; nothing is being returned from the `countUp` method.
- The call to `setTimeout` doesn't block, meaning it will return *immediately* after being called and the callback function passed to it is scheduled for execution *asynchronously* after the timeout has passed. So every `setTimeout` call in the `for` loop will be executed all at once after 100 ms instead of staggered.

You will need to store the current counter value as data on the component so Vue knows to rerender when its value is changed.

The simplest example I can provide follows, but you might want to encapsulate the logic in a separate reusable component.

```js
const value = 50

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    counter: 0,
  },

  methods: {
    countUp() {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.counter++
        
        if (this.counter >= value) {
          clearInterval(interval)
        }
      }, 100)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="countUp">Count Up</button>
  {{ counter }}
</div>
```

Comment: so my issue with this answer is it doesnt taken in a value and return a value like I want to be able to pass in a number to the method return the number 0 immediately and then have that number change, without having to create a variable for each counter, but i totally understand why the setTimeout wouldnt of worked

Comment: It's impossible to do it the way you described; Vue's reactivity system doesn't support it. The counter value needs to be a reactive property on the component so Vue can observe changes to it. If you encapsulate this logic in a separate component then it'll be easier to manage.

Comment: @SmokeyDawson also keep in mind that if u are running it in ssr mode than using intervals will leak to memory leaks